# On the relation between the vectorization and the half vectorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectorization

From *Matrix Variate Distributions* by Gupta & Nagar.

#### 1) definition of vectorization for a generic matrix (page 9)

Let $X$ be a $m\times n$ matrix and let $X_1$, $\dots$, $X_n$ be the columns of $X$ (which are column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$).
Define the vectorization of $X$ as the column vector in $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$
\begin{equation}\operatorname{vec}[X]\triangleq \begin{bmatrix}X_1 \\ \vdots\\ X_n\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}

#### 2) definition of vectorization for a symmetric matrix - aka half vectorization (page 10)

Let $X$ be a $p\times p$ matrix and denote the typical element as $X_{ij}$. Define the vectorization of $X$ as the column vector in $\mathbb{R}^{p(p+1)/2}$ formed by the elements above and including the diagonal, taken columnwise, i.e.
\begin{equation}\operatorname{vecp}[X]=\begin{bmatrix}X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{22} & \cdots & X_{1p} & \cdots & X_{pp}\end{bmatrix}=\operatorname{vecp}[X']\end{equation}
where $X'$ is the transpose of $X$.

#### 3) definition of transition matrix (page 11)

The matrix $B_p$ of order $p^2\times\frac{1}{2}p(p+1)$ with typical element
\begin{equation}(B_p)_{ij,gh}=\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{ig}\delta_{jh}+\delta_{ih}\delta_{jg}) \qquad i\leq p, j\leq p, g\leq h\leq p\end{equation}
where $\delta_{rs}$ is the Kronecker's delta, is called transition matrix.

#### 4) theorem (page 11)

if $X$ is a symmetric matrix of order $p\times p$ then
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{vecp}[X]&= B_p' \operatorname{vec}[X]\\
\operatorname{vec}[X]&= (B_p^+)' \operatorname{vecp}[X]\\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
where $B_p^+\triangleq (B_p' B_p)^{-1}B_p'$

#### 5) observation (page 11)

$B_p^+$ is of order $\frac{1}{2}p(p+1)\times p^2$ with typical element
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}(B_p^+)_{gh,ij}&=(2-\delta_{gh})(B_p)_{ij,gh} \qquad i\leq p, j \leq p, g \leq h \leq p \\
&=1, \qquad ij = gh \text{ or } ij=hg\\
&=0, \qquad \text{otherwise} \end{aligned}\end{equation}

---

#### my question

To me, is not clear the definition of transition matrix. Firstly, I'm not sure if I have understood correctly the meaning of the symbol $\delta_{rs}$, I believe it means
\begin{equation}\delta_{rs}\triangleq \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } r=s \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\end{equation}
Moreover, the notation used to represent the indexes of the typical element $(B_p)_{ij}$ seems to me erroneus, and I will give you a simple example in a moment.
I've reported the theorem and the observation because maybe provide some useful information to understand the definition of transition matrix. Moreover, I have found something similar to my problem in [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplication_and_elimination_matrices) on wikipedia, where the "elimination matrix" seems to be $B_p$, while the "duplication matrix" seems to be $B_p^+$.

#### example

Consider the simple case $p=2$. Thanks to the theorem we can do some retro-engineering to discover who is $B_2$. The vectorizations in this case are
\begin{equation}\operatorname{vec}[X]=\begin{bmatrix}X_{11} & X_{21} & X_{12} & X_{22}\end{bmatrix}'\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\operatorname{vecp}[X]=\begin{bmatrix}X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{22}\end{bmatrix}'\end{equation}
so the matrix that maps $\operatorname{vec}[X]$ into $\operatorname{vecp}[X]$ is
\begin{equation}B_2'=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
consequently, the transition matrix is
\begin{equation}B_2=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
This is the result that I expect by computing the definition of transition matrix. Assuming the previous interpretation of $\delta_{rs}$, I start to compute the elements of $B_2$ according the definition of $B_p$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
i=1, j=1, g=1, h=1:& \qquad B_{11} = \frac{\delta_{11}\delta_{11}+\delta_{11}\delta_{11}}{2}=\frac{1\cdot1+1\cdot1}{2}=1\\
i=1, j=1, g=1, h=2:& \qquad B_{12} = \frac{\delta_{11}\delta_{12}+\delta_{12}\delta_{11}}{2}=\frac{1\cdot0+0\cdot1}{2}=0\\
i=1, j=1, g=2, h=2:& \qquad B_{14} = \frac{\delta_{12}\delta_{12}+\delta_{12}\delta_{12}}{2}=\frac{0\cdot0+0\cdot0}{2}=0\\
i=1, j=2, g=1, h=1:& \qquad B_{21} = \frac{\delta_{11}\delta_{21}+\delta_{11}\delta_{21}}{2}=\frac{1\cdot0+1\cdot0}{2}=0\\
i=1, j=2, g=1, h=2:& \qquad B_{22} = \frac{\delta_{11}\delta_{22}+\delta_{12}\delta_{21}}{2}=\frac{1\cdot1+0\cdot0}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\\
i=1, j=2, g=2, h=2:& \qquad B_{24} = \frac{\delta_{12}\delta_{22}+\delta_{12}\delta_{22}}{2}=\frac{0\cdot1+0\cdot1}{2}=0\\
i=2, j=1, g=1, h=1:& \qquad B_{21} = \frac{\delta_{21}\delta_{11}+\delta_{21}\delta_{11}}{2}=\frac{0\cdot1+0\cdot1}{2}=0\\
i=2, j=1, g=1, h=2:& \qquad B_{22} = \frac{\delta_{21}\delta_{12}+\delta_{22}\delta_{11}}{2}=\frac{0\cdot0+1\cdot1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\\
i=2, j=1, g=2, h=2:& \qquad B_{24} = \frac{\delta_{22}\delta_{12}+\delta_{22}\delta_{12}}{2}=\frac{1\cdot0+1\cdot0}{2}=0\\
i=2, j=2, g=1, h=1:& \qquad B_{41} = \frac{\delta_{21}\delta_{21}+\delta_{21}\delta_{21}}{2}=\frac{0\cdot0+0\cdot0}{2}=0\\
i=2, j=2, g=1, h=2:& \qquad B_{42} = \frac{\delta_{21}\delta_{22}+\delta_{22}\delta_{21}}{2}=\frac{0\cdot1+1\cdot0}{2}=0\\
i=2, j=2, g=2, h=2:& \qquad B_{44} = \frac{\delta_{22}\delta_{22}+\delta_{22}\delta_{22}}{2}=\frac{1\cdot1+1\cdot1}{2}=1\\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
so I conclude that
\begin{equation}B_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & ? & 0\\
0 & 1/2 & ? & 0 \\
? & ?   & ? & ? \\
0 & 0 & ? & 1
 \end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
which is clearly wrong.

---

#### update

I've found [this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/j.2333-8504.1973.tb00197.x), where some insight on the notation are given.

First, $(B_p)_{ij,gh}$ is a "4 indexes" notation, and not a "2 indexes" notation where one have to take the products $ij$, $gh$ to reduce the 4 indexes to 2 indexes.

Second, equation 4 says that in the special case of the direct product (which I believe is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)), this "4 indexes" notation assumes the meaning
\begin{equation}[A\otimes B]_{ij, gh}=a_{jh}b_{ig}\end{equation}
where, I believe, $a_{jh}$ is the element of row $j$ and column $h$ of $A$ (and the same for $b_{ig}$).

Third, in this paper is written, using the notation of Gupta & Nagar, that
for $B_p$ hold the following relations
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}(B_p)_{ii,ii}&=1\\
(B_p)_{ij,ij}&=1/2 \qquad i\neq j\\
(B_p)_{ij,ji}&=1/2 \qquad i\neq j\\
(B_p)_{ij,gh}&=0 \qquad ij\neq gh \text{ and } ij\neq hg\\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question since January ?
I have the exact same question, it would be nice if someone could explain clearly how to construct $B_p$ and give some examples for small $p$'s.

Comment: In your notation, $B_2'$ and $B_2$ are $\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 4}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{4 \times 3}$ but the one you create based on your index is $\mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$. So, there is something wrong with the way you go over the indices!

Answer (score 1):

The transition matrix (a.k.a elimination matrix) is not unique. Consider $X$ being a symmetric $(2 \times 2)$ matrix, i.e. $x_{2,1} = x_{1,2}$, then

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_{1,1} \\
 x_{2,1} \\
 x_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1-c & c & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_{1,1} \\
 x_{2,1} \\
    x_{1,2} \\
 x_{2,2}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Intuition: For every row in the elimination matrix that is supposed to pick out an off-diagonal element of $X$ you can take $1-c$ times the entry in the lower triangluar part and $c$ times the element in the upper triangular part.

For $c = 1$ you get the canonical elimination matrix. For $c=\frac{1}{2}$ you get the Moore-Penrose inverse of the duplication matrix.